# move file between two different filesystems using file.renameTo returns false

Tags: java, docker, filesystems, kubernetes-pvc, file-move

`file.renameTo` method returns false, in `docker container`. I am using `PVC` in container instance.

I tried removing PVC, then it works fine, but when I use PVC then returns false

Returns false means file is not getting moved or renamed .

In my case, the file is moved from `PVC` location into the docker container specified location.

When we enable `PVC` on `Kubernetes` cluster then storage is on a different `filesystem`.

I think this issue is related to file move from one filesystem to another file system. because when PVC is not enabled then `file.renameTo` works fine, but when PVC is enabled then it fails.

So my question is what are the possible ways to fix this. I cannot disable `PVC` so what is the possible solution to move a file from one filesystem to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my assumption, when we use `PVC` then your storage is at a different location and your docker container is at a different location.

So file move, in this case, is a bit complex. The solution I used, in this case, is file copy and paste at the destination location.

```
public void copyFile(File pvcFileLocation, File dockerContainerLocation){

      FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pvcFileLocation);
      FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dockerContainerLocation);
      int b = -1;
      while ((b = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(b);
      }
      inputStream.close();
      outputStream.close();
    }
```